# Sysprep fails when using Microsoft Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, sysprep

```
Sysprep Fails when creating a new Template in Microsoft Virtual Machine Manager:

Error (706) 
Sysprep failed for virtual machine VMName 

Recommended Action 
Try the operation again.
```

Is there a more detailed log available for this error?  This error is not helpful.  This same configuration worked previously, but now fails consistently.

**Update**

The issue was that the VHD was locked by another process.  Cloning and sysprepping the clone worked fine.

Comment: I don't use sysprep, since I deploy thin images, so I may be wrong, but shouldn't you sysprep a machine **before** you image/clone it and not part of the post-deployment workflow?

Comment: From the wording of the question, I inferred that the OP had a VM, installed Windows in it and was preparing to sysprep that Windows instance for imaging.  That's how I managed imaging because it was far easier to just snapshot before making changes.  It was a huge time-saver in the case of a mistake or a later change.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?  Any more info to add?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your rearm count?  You only get 4 (considering you're using something newer than XP).  Check your rearms by running this in a command prompt (run as admin):

```
slmgr /dlv
```

I also remember seeing something about stopping services when I used to image in Fusion (yes, I built Windows images on a Mac!)  Check into the Media Sharing service and see if stopping it makes a difference.

Here are log file locations for different sysprep options:

- generalize: %WINDIR%\System32\Sysprep\Panther
- specialize: %WINDIR%\Panther
- Unattended Windows setup actions: %WINDIR%\Panther\Unattendgc

Hope this helps!